# Hadoop installation error

Tags: hadoop, failed-installation

I am having a difficulty in running the command start-dfs.sh , whenever i run this command, it will show this error. I have tried correcting it by the ssh-keygen and I have no idea how to solve the problem already. Would appreciate if anyone can help me solving this

I've followed this tutorial:http://www.tecmint.com/install-configure-apache-hadoop-centos-7/

The tutorial is very good but I can't seem to detect the problem.

do refer to this image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a problem with your ssh keys. Try below

```
$ ssh-keygen -t dsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_dsa
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
$ chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And paste `id_rsa.pub` in all other nodes

Comment: It should be hadoop installing user